# Meaning and implications of "non-entry into the European phase"

Tags: european, non-entry

A U.S. Patent that was applied for in 2014 is still shown as Pending (not granted). In 2016 I see a record of the European patent as "non-entry in European phase" code 122. There is also a record with code 121 that precedes the non-entry record.

1. Does "non-entry" mean the patent was declined in that region?
2. Is there a implication about the possible future status of the U.S. patent give that non-entry?
3. If the patent was approved (it's been 4 years), are there strong monetary reasons to not actually get the patent?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 3):

1. 'non entry' means the applicant did not file with EPO for national phase stage after wipo (PCT) stage.
2. This has no implication on patent application with USPTO.
3. Patent prosecution in USPTO sometimes take much more than your expected four years.

After approval i.e. notice of allowance and fees due, if the applicant does not pay fees due in time allowed than the application is not issued (not granted) and also after a patent is issued if maintenance fee (if due) is not paid than the patent is treated as abandoned.